# Is it possible to use classes compiled by Gradle buildSrc in main Groovy project?

Tags: groovy, build, gradle

Classes compiled by buildSrc/build.gradle are not resolved at runtime when they are used in main PROJECT classes.

```
My Groovy project structure looks like this:
-PROJECT
    -buildSrc/
        -build.gradle
        -/src/main/groovy
            - com.company.global.test.report
    -src/test/groovy
    -build.gradle
```

Is there something I can add to the top-level PROJECT/build.gradle to allow the classes compiled by it to use the classes compiled by buildSrc/build.gradle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`buildSrc` is its own *build* (not project) that gets executed before the main build. Its sole purpose is to make some classes (plugins, tasks, regular classes) available to the *build scripts* of the main build. Hence you could call it a "meta-build".

Technically, it would be possible to add the compiled classes of `buildSrc` to the compile or runtime class path of a project in the main build, but I don't recommend to do it. There is very likely a better way to achieve your goals (but I don't know what those are).

Comment: Peter, thank you for the explanation. Until recently, the only class in my buildSrc was one used by the main build.gradle; now there is some refactoring going on, that is putting several related classes together. I will find a different way to solve this problem rather than trying to force buildSrc to do something it isn't intended to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it with Gradle `2.12`:

In `your_project/buildSrc/build.gradle`

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
  classifier = 'sources'
  from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

// Thanks to this, IDE like IntelliJ will provide you with "Navigate to sources"
artifacts {
  archives sourcesJar
}
```

In `your_project/build.gradle`

```
ext.buildSrcJars = fileTree("$rootDir/buildSrc/build/libs") { include("*.jar") exclude("*sources.jar")}

// Works in every subproject
dependencies {
    compile buildSrcJars
}
```