# How to share some classes with buildSrc and one of subprojects?

Tags: gradle

I have several classes that initially were used only in buildSrc. But now I need them in subproject A2 as well.

```
| - rootProject A
    | - buildSrc
    | - subproject A1
    | - subproject A2
```

- Option 1. Leave those classes in buildSrc and try to add `implementation(":buildSrc")` to dependencies of A2. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I can't link to buildSrc, gradle says something like "there's no 'buildSrc' subproject in project A".
- Option 2. Using of `implementation(files("${project.rootDir}/buildSrc/build/classes/"))` in subproject A2 doesn't work as well. It builds, but classes from buildSrc are not accessible in A2's sources.
- Option 3. Okay. Let's extract those classes in a new subproject A3. And here, again, failure. buildSrc can't have dependency on any of A's projects. Otherwise it'd a circular dependency.
- Option 4. Well, then we can extract it to a separate rootProject B and create composite build. In A's `settings.gradle.kts` I've put `includeBuild("B")`. And again, I can use it in A2 as `implementation("mygroup:B")` and can't use it in buildSrc: `Could not find mygroup:B.\n Required by:\n project :`

So, what options do I still have ? Or may be I did something wrong in my previous attempts ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use classes compiled by Gradle buildSrc in main Groovy project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930646/is-it-possible-to-use-classes-compiled-by-gradle-buildsrc-in-main-groovy-project)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can use option 4 as of Gradle 6.7

See [Issue #3768](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3768) and the [related release notes in v6.7](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7-rc-1/release-notes.html#build-src)

"Included builds are now visible to buildSrc
We recommend that builds use the specially named buildSrc build to organize imperative and common build logic.

Sometimes, you may also need to share build logic between buildSrc itself and your root build. In the previous releases, that was not possible because buildSrc could not access build logic from other included builds.

In this release, it's now possible to share build logic between buildSrc and the root build or any other included build. This makes it easier to share common repository declarations or conventions between buildSrc and other builds as demonstrated in this sample."

Comment: I was initially using Gradle 6.7. But as far as I understand, it's about plugins, so about sharing code with buildSrc's build file and subproject's build file. But I need those classes in buildSrc/src and subproject/src.

Comment: May be it's a bug and I can create an issue ?

Comment: Put the "common" code in its own separate build which is included via a composite. You should then be able to use "common" in "anotherProject/buildSrc" or "anotherProject/subProject". The only place you can't use the "common" logic is in "common/buildSrc" (only as of Gradle 6.7)

Comment: I swear It doesn't work. "anotherProject/buildSrc" builds with error. [please check](https://gist.github.com/yevhenii8/2ed23d9bb537fadce8fb716577c9a1f7) May be I did something wrong ?

Comment: No, that's wrong. Reference the artifact from an included build via it's group:artifact:version as if it came from a repository, not via :project-name. Eg same as you would reference the spring jars or mockito or an external dependency

Comment: Oh nope, It wasn't via :project-name. That artifact doesn't have group & version declared. Gradle defaults are empty strings. Anyway I had tried specifying group and version. There's no change. still works in another subproject and doesn't in buildsrc with the same error.

Comment: I was wrong. Error's message changes [a bit](https://ibb.co/QKMZ5bg)

Comment: Try building [the project referenced in issue #3768](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-composite-bug). Does that work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223892/discussion-between-yevhenii-nadtochii-and-lance-java).

Comment: I've added a reply in chat